# Regular expression to find string in middle

Tags: regex

The raw string

```
<li><a href="/string/FIXED-123546">Value A
</a></li><li> <a href="/string/FIXED-265485">
Value B</a></li><li><a href="/string/FIXED-343">
Value C</a></li>
```

I wish to find the string:

**123456ValueA**

**265485ValuB**

**343ValueC**

If this is difficult, finding something like this will do "***123546">Value A***"

I'm new to regex and only manage to have this regex, of course it does't work fine: **FIXED(.*)</a>**

Anyone can help?

**Edited:**

I dont use any programming language here, i will use some kind of regex editor to extract the string for one time use.

Online regex tool i will use:

http://www.regexr.com/

http://regex101.com/

Comment: You'd better use specialized HTML parsing methods/libraries. But in case if you are limited to regex and your regex engine supports look arounds, then the following regex will work for you: `(?<=FIXED-).*?(?=</a>)`.

Comment: What flavor of regex you are going to use? which language it is?

Comment: [Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) is a great resource for newbies to regex. The linked tutorial about greediness vs laziness should really help you understand what's going on here.

Comment: `FIXED[-](\d+)["]>([^<]+)` should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex matches your targets:

```
FIXED-(\d+)">([^<]*)
```

Join together groups 1 and 2

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/CZinmE6LxY)

Comment: I may be dense, but do we really need the lookbehind there? Wouldn't `FIXED-(.*?)">([^<]*)` be enough? Also, couldn't we use `FIXED-(\d+)">([^<]*)` instead of the lazy star for better performance?

Comment: @SáT sure. I've incorporated your suggestions.